# May banks ignore the vol surface for far OTM, distantly-dated options, and make risk decisions only on near-term implied ATM vol?

Tags: volatility, risk-management, volatility-surface, volatility-skew, smile

Here is a difficult "real-life" skew / surface options problem that actually occurred. Please help me judge its validity or falsity.

In 2018 a Chinese communications stock was falling, and its proxy on the local exchange realized almost 50% (over 60 working days). Its long-term mean vol was about 30%. It's proxy's options were extremely illiquid with almost no open interest. We held most open interest.

We had 2 large options positions. They were both far out of the money, and also highly long-dated. Strikes were at 80% and 89% moneyness. Expiry was 1.1 year, and 2.4 years away. We were short the first (puts), and long the second (calls).

Now the exchange wanted to raise the ATM mark-to-model moneyness of the first one (expiring in a year) from 22% up by quite a few percent. I was not worried, because the exchange is open to changing the surface to reflect open interest (implied vols, "where the market trades"). In fact, about 15% of skews on the exchange were custom skews at this time. As such, I expected no major MTM cash flows.

However, the broker's man panicked. He forgot about the natural reshaping of the surface and the skew, and convinced himself that all now rests on the ATM near-term realized vol. As such he came to the conclusion that the position will suck in $150k a day until it all defaults. He also did not understand that vol spikes were temporary, and return back to the mean in a type of sinusoidal curve.

This panic had a bad effect (he was also going through a personal crisis). He informed his bosses and his bank that the positions are doomed, and will suck in $150k a day until it all defaults.

He believed the vol spike would be permanent, and forgot about the fact that a 1 dimensional near-term ATM vol has little bearing in the 3d world of far out the money, and distantly expiring positions. He informed everyone a default is about to happen, and then checked himself into a mental health facility (!)

So the brokers and its bank panicked. They held a meeting with the Exchange, and the Exchange then said they will keep the ATM vol at 22% for now, leading to no cash flows for daily MTM other than the usual (delta, etc - it was also delta neutral). The Exchange, in effect, said to them: "stop panicking".

I also calculated that even if they put up the near-term ATM vol from 22% to 36%, correction in the surface could actually benefit us.

However, the bank's man and the broker's boss only understood the near-term ATM vol, They had no understanding of the far OTM, long-dated surface. As a result the bank demanded double or triple margin deposit from the broker immediately (a loophole in the regulations allows them to do so).

As such, the broker undertook an immediate fire-sale in a non-existent, illiquid small options market (in South Africa). While the exchange valued the positions at a positive number, they got rid of the positions immediately to the trading department of their own bank, who priced the positions at -$250k and took the profit.

Now the broker is demanding this $250k from us.

(Incidentally, ignoring the further positive effect of the delta, the options themselves expired with over $5 mil profit to those who ended up taking them.)

Please could I ask for a comment on this situation?

Thank you, Best regards,

Comment: There's a saying (often [misattributed](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/08/09/remain-solvent/)) that goes "The market can stay irrational a lot longer than you can stay solvent."  This situation has some of that flavor, though the way you were railroaded by the broker and bank goes beyond that.  One way you can think of the whole farrago is that you understood your _financial_ risks, but had not accounted for _counterparty_ risk and _contract_ risk -- especially for such a concentrated position in which they could single your firm out for their "panic" (which may only have been an act).

Comment: Thank you for your wisdom